# How to determine the last row of the print area in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, page-break

I have a large table, which does not always fit on a print page. If the table does not fit on one print page, script must write "Contunue on next page" into last row of current page. How to do it?

Comment: Do you mean a database table? Are you displaying on a webpage? Or are you reading content from an Excel file and displaying on a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are building a page updated by javascript.
I can provide 2 answers here:

- from a usability point of view, you should add "next page" both
  before and after the table. By then, a user that is searching for a
  specific page don't have to scroll down all the page to go to next
  page
- from a technical point of view, there's no reason to put the next
  page inside the table. Just put it into a  and just name it if
  you need to access to it later on.

In case my guess wasn't correct, can you please give more detail about your problem (includig relevant code snippets)?